# Usar a função increment do DB para atualizar a partir de um array

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

É o seguinte: Tenho um array em javascript com as id que quero incrementar usando o`DB::table('team').increment->('points', 1000).` Como devo fazer o meu controller pegar esse array e incrementar somente as id que estão nele?

Comment: você está enviando como? se tem o código javascript?

Comment: Ai que tá. No script eu gravo em um array e consigo mandar ele para um input hidden separando cada id por virgulas. Mas não tenho ideia de como mandar isso para o meu controller. Eu criei uma função score() mas não consegui implementar ela pra receber esses dados

Comment: Coloque o script que você grava o array?

Comment: `var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var selected = id.charAt(id.length-5);
                var team = id.charAt(id.length-3);
                var order = id.charAt(id.length-1);
                selections[order] = [parseInt(team),parseInt(selected),id];`